# Keras: losing axis with brightness_range during image augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, multidimensional-array, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I'm training a U-net based segmentation network and using keras' `ImageDataGenerator` for inline augmentation of my grayscale images. Everything works as expected unless I include `brightness_range` in my arguments. When this happens my 512,512,1 image seems to turn into a 512,512 image and messes things up. How do I fix this?

Here's my augmentation code:

```
data_gen_args = dict(
    rotation_range=15,
    shear_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=[0.5,1.5],
    #horizontal_flip=True,
    #vertical_flip=True,
    brightness_range=[0.5,1.5],
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

image_datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)


train_image_generator = image_datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
train_ct,
target_size = (512, 512),
color_mode = ("grayscale"),
classes=None,
class_mode=None,
seed = seed,
batch_size = BS)

train_mask_generator = mask_datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
train_mask,
target_size = (512, 512),
color_mode = ("grayscale"),
classes=None,
class_mode=None,
seed = seed,
batch_size = BS)
```

And here's my error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-8d701f27a3fa> in <module>
      7                     verbose=1,
      8                     callbacks=cb_check,
----> 9                     use_multiprocessing = False
     10                              )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1730             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1731             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1732             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1733 
   1734     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    183             batch_index = 0
    184             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
--> 185                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
    186 
    187                 if not hasattr(generator_output, '__len__'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get(self)
    740                     "`use_multiprocessing=False, workers > 1`."
    741                     "For more information see issue #1638.")
--> 742             six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get(self)
    709                 try:
    710                     future = self.queue.get(block=True)
--> 711                     inputs = future.get(timeout=30)
    712                     self.queue.task_done()
    713                 except mp.TimeoutError:

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    117         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    118         try:
--> 119             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    120         except Exception as e:
    121             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py in next_sample(uid)
    648         The next value of generator `uid`.
    649     """
--> 650     return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])
    651 
    652 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 104         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     def next(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in next(self)
    114         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    115         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 116         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    117 
    118     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    244                 x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(x, params)
    245                 x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
--> 246             batch_x[i] = x
    247         # optionally save augmented images to disk for debugging purposes
    248         if self.save_to_dir:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape (512,512,1)
```

Comment: I have used brightness_range in ImageDataGenerator and it didn't cause any problem. The model worked perfectly fine. Can you please recheck the data source dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the model where I have used brightness_range in ImageDataGenerator and it didn't cause any problem. The model worked perfectly fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our training cat pictures
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our training dog pictures
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our validation cat pictures
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our validation dog pictures

num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
num_dogs_tr = len(os.listdir(train_dogs_dir))

num_cats_val = len(os.listdir(validation_cats_dir))
num_dogs_val = len(os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir))

total_train = num_cats_tr + num_dogs_tr
total_val = num_cats_val + num_dogs_val

batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", 
          loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=total_val // batch_size)
```

Output-

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-2-2b8537e7d5b3>:74: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Epoch 1/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 591ms/step - loss: 1.0527 - accuracy: 0.5010 - val_loss: 0.6918 - val_accuracy: 0.5089
Epoch 2/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 609ms/step - loss: 0.6790 - accuracy: 0.5337 - val_loss: 0.6473 - val_accuracy: 0.5647
Epoch 3/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 610ms/step - loss: 0.6340 - accuracy: 0.5983 - val_loss: 0.6208 - val_accuracy: 0.6172
Epoch 4/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 609ms/step - loss: 0.5899 - accuracy: 0.6464 - val_loss: 0.5938 - val_accuracy: 0.6585
Epoch 5/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 599ms/step - loss: 0.5182 - accuracy: 0.7286 - val_loss: 0.6165 - val_accuracy: 0.7042
Epoch 6/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 608ms/step - loss: 0.4697 - accuracy: 0.7682 - val_loss: 0.5853 - val_accuracy: 0.7109
Epoch 7/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 604ms/step - loss: 0.4393 - accuracy: 0.7746 - val_loss: 0.5826 - val_accuracy: 0.7132
Epoch 8/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 608ms/step - loss: 0.4115 - accuracy: 0.7895 - val_loss: 0.6602 - val_accuracy: 0.7042
Epoch 9/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 598ms/step - loss: 0.3831 - accuracy: 0.8162 - val_loss: 0.6254 - val_accuracy: 0.7076
Epoch 10/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 601ms/step - loss: 0.3151 - accuracy: 0.8531 - val_loss: 0.5924 - val_accuracy: 0.7098
Epoch 11/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 611ms/step - loss: 0.2904 - accuracy: 0.8632 - val_loss: 0.6664 - val_accuracy: 0.6964
Epoch 12/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 604ms/step - loss: 0.2524 - accuracy: 0.8921 - val_loss: 0.7111 - val_accuracy: 0.6752
Epoch 13/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 592ms/step - loss: 0.2143 - accuracy: 0.9081 - val_loss: 0.7246 - val_accuracy: 0.6953
Epoch 14/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 599ms/step - loss: 0.1829 - accuracy: 0.9284 - val_loss: 0.7323 - val_accuracy: 0.7221
Epoch 15/15
15/15 [==============================] - 9s 598ms/step - loss: 0.1469 - accuracy: 0.9460 - val_loss: 0.8435 - val_accuracy: 0.6998
```